# SQL Server -- CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT to query Parquet files via Polybase -- failing due to TCP error

Tags: sql-server, parquet, sql-server-2019, polybase

**Context:** I'm trying to use SQL Server's Polybase to query data in parquet files. One of the steps required to do so is to create an external file format that [maps to parquet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=parquet). MSDN provides SQL sample below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT parquet_file_format
WITH (  
FORMAT_TYPE = PARQUET,  
--DATA_COMPRESSION = 'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec'
DATA_COMPRESSION = 'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec'
);
```

When I execute it I get the following error.

> OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Login timeout expired".
> OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".
> Msg 10061, Level 16, State 1, Line 40
> TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I've tried [enabling TCP network protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-or-disable-a-server-network-protocol?view=sql-server-ver15)

[image]

and also tried configuring the [remote access server configuration option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15) neither of which resolve the error.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'remote access', 0 ;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO
```

**Question:** Can someone please point me in the right direction, or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out issue was Polybase services weren't running. I was able to run them in the sql server configuraion manager under sql server network configuration. This was helpful: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/polybase-syntax-error